# if/else on digitalRead not executing on 'else' portion

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, led

I am a beginner with C++ but used to be good with BASIC (2 decades ago lol). I'm building a peristaltic metered doser that allows you to input desired mL on a 4x4 keypad and then when 'fill' button is pressed it doses the desired mLs through the peristaltic.

I'm still drafting/printing the peristaltic housing and all of that but in the meantime I want to get as much of the coding done as possible. It's still incomplete, but one of the functions I want the doser to have is a 'PRIME/FLUSH' button.

Originally I wanted the button to run the pump as long as the button is held down to prime the tubing with solution or flush the tubing with DI water. But I haven't had luck figuring out how to use a 4x4 button in momentary switch mode.

A workaround I had was to have the button be an on/off button. So press it once, pump turns on, press it again, pump turns off. Since the pump isn't printed yet I've been using the onboard LED as a tester for the coding (hence the LED_BUILTIN).

The issue, from my research I figured what I would need was an if/else statement. When the button is pressed (in this case the 'a' button), it reads the LED_BUILTIN status and if its HIGH it turns it off and if its LOW it turns it on.

But the 'if' part is working, it turns it on, but the 'else' part is not. When the LED is already on and the 'a' button is pressed, it stays on and doesn't rewrite to LOW.

Code below, any advice?

```
#include <KeypadShield.h>

KeypadShield keypad;

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);

char Data[15];
byte data_count = 0;

int x;

char customKey;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  keypad.begin();
  lcd.begin(20,4); 
    lcd.setCursor(4,0);
    lcd.print("Let's Fill!");
    lcd.setCursor(4,1);
    lcd.print("Designed by");
    lcd.setCursor(4,2);
    lcd.print("JP");
    lcd.setCursor(5,3);
    lcd.print("2019 v1.0");

    delay (2000);

    lcd.clear();

    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("Enter volume in mL");
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print("on keypad then");
    lcd.setCursor(5,2);
    lcd.print("press DONE");
    lcd.setCursor(0,3);
    lcd.print("mL:");
}

void softReset()
{
asm volatile ("  jmp 0");
}

void loop() 
{
    customKey = keypad.getNextKeypress();

    if (customKey) 
    {
      if (customKey == 'a') 
      {
        if (digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN == LOW)) 
        {
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(5,1);
          lcd.print("FLUSHING");
        } 
        else
        {
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(1,0);
          lcd.print("Enter volume in mL");
          lcd.setCursor(3,1);
          lcd.print("on keypad then");
          lcd.setCursor(5,2);
          lcd.print("press DONE");
          lcd.setCursor(0,3);
          lcd.print("mL:");
        }
      }

      if (customKey == 'd')
      {
       softReset();
      }

      if (customKey != 'p' && customKey != 'a' && customKey != 'b' && customKey != 'c' && customKey != 'd' && customKey != 's')
      {
        Data[data_count] = customKey; // store char into data array
        lcd.setCursor(data_count+3,4); // move cursor to show each new char
        lcd.print(Data[data_count]); // print char at said cursor
        data_count++; // increment data array by 1 to store new char, also keep track of the number of chars entered
        x = atoi (Data); //convert string to integer 'x' for use in equations
      }

     if (customKey == 'p')
      {
       lcd.clear();
       lcd.setCursor(7,0);
        lcd.print(x);
        lcd.setCursor(Data[data_count]+13,0);
        lcd.print("mL");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("FILL --> fill");
        lcd.setCursor(0,2);
        lcd.print("RESET --> change mL");
        lcd.setCursor(0,3);
        lcd.print("FLUSH --> finish");

      }
    }
};
```

Comment: `digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) == LOW` move the `)`. (you read a LED?)

Comment: Holy crow... thanks Juraj. Brain fart right there... that fixed the issue! And yes, the LED right now is just a placeholder for my peristaltic pump (once I finish drafting and printing the housing). I'm just using it to make sure everything works. Thanks again!

Comment: the pump can be read?

Comment: @Juraj I was thinking I could read whether or not the pump was on or off, or some variation of the concept

Comment: by accident on Uno you will read the pin state last set, but better have a state variable

Comment: You may remove the ';' at the very end of the sketch. If you do not know all the consequences of a soft reset, then you should not use it. We don't use it, for a good reason. When the microcontroller of the arduino uno is powered on, everything is in a off-state. That means that no internal parts (timers, bus controllers, and so on) needs to be initialized. That's why it is so easy to use for small projects and for an arduino board. With a soft reset, you continue at the beginning of the code. If something was wrong and in a wrong state, then the soft reset might make it worse.

Answer (score 7):

(Heh... before even seeing the code I guessed you'd done this...)

You are comparing a pin number, not the results of `digitalRead()`, and then passing the results of that comparison to `digitalRead()`:

```
if (digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN == LOW))
```

It should read:

```
if (digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) == LOW)
```

Note the order of the brackets:  `LED_BUILTIN` is passed to `digitalRead()`, and then the result of calling that function is compared to the value `LOW`.

Comment: Thanks Majenko! Major brain fart on my part... but that solved the issue. haha. Spend so much time looking for the big problems that the little ones just stay right under your nose...

Comment: @Jay Absolutely. It's called "Code Blindness".